# How align item in HTML with responsiveness?

Tags: html, css, responsive

How to create a responsive and proper html

I tried to code but eventually it does not fit, I want `p` tag in on one left end and
`span` on right end in `droppable` class with `p` tag and `span` tag should have 80:20 ratio

```css
.draggable {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: move;
}

.droppable {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.missing-words_blank {
    border: 1px dashed red;
    width: 15%;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="droppable">
        <p>City Names</p>
        <span class="missing-words_blank target"><span id="1"> Noida </span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="droppable">
        <p>Country Names</p>
        <span class="missing-words_blank target"><span id="2"> Maharashtra </span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="droppable">
        <p>State Names</p>
        <span class="missing-words_blank target"><span id="3"> Country </span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: easiest way to do with the use of flex-box or inline-flex

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps or you can be more specific

```
.draggable {
 width: 100px;
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
 background: red;
 color: #fff;
 cursor: move;
}
.droppable {
 width: 300px;
 padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
 margin: 10px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.container {
 width: 100%;
 
}
.missing-words_blank {
 border: 1px dashed red;
 width: 15%;
 height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**this may help**

```css
  .droppable {
        width: 300px;
        padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
        margin: 10px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-item: center;
    }
    .droppable p{
    
        width:80%;
    }
        
    .droppable span{
    
        width:20%;
    }
```